# PropertyGrid: Merging multiple dynamic properties when editing multiple objects

Tags: .net, propertygrid

Let's say I have a class A and a class B. I would like to edit using .NET PropertyGrid multiple instances of A and B simultaneously. The desired behavior would be to have the intersection of properties displayed.

If A and B have static (written in the source code) properties everything works fine. Selecting A and B instances will only display the intersection of properties.

However, if A and B also have dynamic properties (returned as a PropertyDescriptorCollection through the GetProperties() method) the behavior is wrong. When selecting multiple objects I will only see those static properties and none of the dynamic ones.

When I select only one instance I can see all properties (static and dynamic).

Anybody any ideas? I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Comment: Can you post some code for the dynamic properties objects?

Comment: It's ok .. i've moved to another approach.
It's a wrapper over multiple objects, that exposes itself to the property grid as a single instance. I manually intersect properties for the given object list and give it to the PropertyGrid and then for each property I propagate any changes to the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the MergablePropertyAttribute on the properties?

Comment: Yes i've tried that but it didn't work.
I also tried replicating the list of attributes of static properties but that didn't work either (note that the static properties didn't even have the mergeable attribute set).